# wpf listbox/listview : grouped by header, but if only one item exists, only show the header?

Tags: wpf, listview, listbox, command, grouping

Basically I have the following setup:

```
public class Sections
{
    public String Heading { get; set; }

    public String SectionTitle { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MyTask> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Right now I can do the following (Group all items by header and show their tasks under them):

- Heading1

  - Section1

    1. DoX (Clickable)
    2. DoY (Clickable)
  - Section2

    1. DoFoo (Clickable)
    2. DoBar (Clickable)
- Heading2

  - SectionX

    1. DoSomething (Clickable)
  - SectionY

    1. DoSomethingElse (Clickable)
- Heading3

  - SpecialSection

    1. AccessSpecialSection (Clickable)

What I'm trying to achieve is to condense this list down:

- Heading1

  - Section1

    1. DoX
    2. DoY
  - Section2

    1. DoFoo
    2. DoBar
- Heading2

  - SectionX (DoSomething is hidden within this - Now SectionX is Clickable)
  - SectionY (DoSomethingElse is hidden within this - Now SectionY is Clickable)
- Heading3 (SpecialSection / AccessSpecialSection is hidden within this - Now Heading3 is Clickable)

Not sure if there is an easy way to do this?

---

I have a feeling it will require some type of templating? where there are 4 possibilities:

- IF ONE SECTION exists in the Heading AND ONE TASK exists in the Section => Heading gets the command binding
- IF ONE SECTION exists in the Heading AND 2+ TASKS exist in the Section => Show Heading / Hide Section and the TASKS get the command binding
- IF 2+ SECTIONS exist in the Heading and ONE TASK exists in the Section => Show Heading / Show Section / Hide the TASK and give the Section the command binding
- IF 2+ SECTIONS exist in the Heading and 2+ TASKS exist in the Section => Show all and proceed as normal (TASKS get the command binding).